# input field and sign not in the same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i want to have a nested sign in the input tag, like the QM sign at the end (align right). it works but its not the same line height, EUR is bigger than the input field, has anyone an idea ?

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
   <div class="formBlock">
   <label for="price">Wohnfl&auml;che ca.</label><br/>
      <div class="input-group input-group-md">
      <input type="text" name="immo_id" id="immo_id" value="" />
      <div class="input-group-addon">QM</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `form-control` class to your input:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div style="margin-top:100px"></div>
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-6">
   <div class="formBlock">
   <label for="price">Wohnfl&auml;che ca.</label><br/>
      <div class="input-group input-group-md ">
      <input type="text" name="immo_id" id="immo_id" value="" class="form-control"/>
      <div class="input-group-addon">QM</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.form-control` class

> `Form controls` automatically receive some global styling with Bootstrap:
>
> All textual `<input>`, `<textarea>`, and `<select>` elements with class `.form-control` have a width of 100% by default. Wrap labels and controls in .form-group for optimum spacing

We can extend form controls by adding text or buttons before, after, or on both sides of any text-based `<input>`. Use `.input-group` with an `.input-group-addon` to prepend or append elements to a single `.form-control`

```
<div class="formBlock">
   <label for="price">Wohnfläche ca.</label><br>
      <div class="input-group input-group-md">
      <input type="text" name="immo_id" id="immo_id" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon">QM</span>
      </div>
   </div>
```

[**Working Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/rLty2y04/)

Comment: thanks again, how can i disable the blue onfocus color ? or change the color ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rLty2y04/2/ Look at this fiddle just override styles

'input{
outline: none;
box-shadow:none !important;
border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}'@user2083524